# How do I check if the OS is Windows 11 in install4j?

Tags: install4j

I want to check, if the install4j installer runs on a windows 11 system. Otherwise I would like to raise a warning.
Unfortunately I can only find methods for all other Windows versions except for 11.
Can someone help me out?